# End to End Encryption with AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, encryption

Is it possible to ensure End to End Encryption with AWS ALB?
We can encrypt the traffic from the client to the Load Balancer with an AWS generated Certificate. If we have an ASP.NET Core Application in a Container using AWS Fargate and a self signed Certificate in it, how do we let the Load Balancer know of this Certificate and let the Traffic through?

At the moment the Application is shutting down automatically and showing 502 Bad Gateway, and Health Checks not passed.

[image: Logs from the Container]

Comment: Did you also configure the ALB to talk HTTPS to the target? In that case self-signed certificates should actually work.

Comment: Hi @Maurice, yes I actually did. I think it has to do with authentication of the backend instances. According to AWS The ALB can't use backend authentication to authenticate HTTPS connections between the load balancer and backend instances.

Comment: ah, so you want to do mutual TLS?

Comment: @Maurice Yes exactly

Comment: For mutual TLS you need to use a Network Load Balancer with a TCP listener that passes on the connection to the target. That use case isn't supported with the ALB.