# Implementing End-to-End Encryption with AWS ALB for a Web Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, aws-application-load-balancer

I require full encryption for my application during its operation on an EC2 instance. There's an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) directing traffic to the EC2 instance's port, with Route53 managing DNS for the ALB. The TLS configuration on the EC2 instance differs from that on the ALB, where the ALB utilizes AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) for its TLS certificates. Currently, there's a TLS negotiation error occurring at the ALB level. What is the optimal way to resolve this and ensure seamless operation without resorting to self-signed certificates?

I have checked the AWS Private Certificate Authority but it cost me 400$ to 4000$ monthly.

Comment: If I understand what you're proposing, I would not consider this end-to-end encryption.

Comment: See also [End to End Encryption with AWS Application Load Balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150616/end-to-end-encryption-with-aws-application-load-balancer)

Comment: Thanks for checking my question, the link provided by you is about an application running on AWS Fargate, my application is running on my EC2 (on docker)

Comment: It sounds like you just need to install a certificate on the EC2 server. Self signed certificates are commonly used for this. If you don't want self-signed, and you don't want to pay much, I suggest looking into using Let's Encrypt for the certificate on the EC2 server. The ALB does not do any verification of the SSL cert on the backend server, so if you are getting a negotiation error you must not have any certificate installed on the server at all.

Comment: My comment was simply about "end-to-end encryption". If an intermediate system, such as ALB, decrypts and then re-encrypts the traffic on its way to its destination then it's technically not end-to-end.